# Compare column names on local and remote DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a timed sync that references a remote database. The sync uses "Select *...". There have been some changes to the local DB structure, and now the sync fails of course because the columns are different.

How can I compare the two tables?

To get the local columms, I can do:

```
SELECT * -- COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'Items'
ORDER  BY ordinal_position
```

And to get the remote columns I can do:

```
EXECUTE [WebServ].[WebDB].dbo.sp_executesql
N'SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  table_name like ''ITEMS_Web'''
```

But how would I put them together so it just shows me which columns have been added on the local table? I guess I just don't know how to get the results from the Execute command into a useable form so I could do a JOIN or something... Forgive my n00bieness. This is MSSQL 2008

Comment: why have you tagged with mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a stored procedure to modify archive tables for me automatically.

I have modified it for you, leave the @COMMIT_CHANGES=0 and it will print out the alters required to update the 2nd table to match the first.

Be sure you fix the database and owner in the SET statements to match your own database tables.

I have disabled the EXEC that could potentially alter your table in case you accidentally set @COMMIT_CHANGES to 1... un-comment it if you want the @COMMIT_CHANGES flag to actually execute alter codes.  If nothing is returned the tables match.

Edit: I am storing the commands in a table for email to myself, but I removed the email code from this example.

This should give a good foundation for anything you need it to do.

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME VARCHAR(100), @TABLENAME2 VARCHAR(100), @COMMIT_CHANGES BIT, @SSERVERNAME VARCHAR(100)

SET @TABLENAME='database.dbo.ITEMS' --local
SET @TABLENAME2='database.dbo.ITEMS_WEB' --remote
SET @SSERVERNAME = 'WEBSERV' --remote server
SET @COMMIT_CHANGES=0 -- set to 1, and it WILL change your remote table

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @DB1 SYSNAME, @OWNER1 SYSNAME, @TABLE1 SYSNAME
    DECLARE @DB2 SYSNAME, @OWNER2 SYSNAME, @TABLE2 SYSNAME
    DECLARE @RECIPIENTS VARCHAR(500), @ENABLEEMAIL BIT

    IF @COMMIT_CHANGES = 0 PRINT 'TEST MODE ONLY, CHANGES WILL NOT BE MADE'

    -- PARSE TABLE NAME INTO 3 PARTS
    SELECT @TABLE1 = PARSENAME(@TABLENAME, 1)
    SELECT @OWNER1 = PARSENAME(@TABLENAME, 2)
    IF @OWNER1 IS NULL SELECT @OWNER1 = 'DBO'
    SELECT @DB1 = PARSENAME(@TABLENAME, 3) 
    IF @DB1 IS NULL SELECT @DB1 = DB_NAME()

    -- PARSE ARCHIVE TABLE NAME INTO 3 PARTS
    SELECT @TABLE2 = PARSENAME(@TABLENAME2, 1)
    SELECT @OWNER2 = PARSENAME(@TABLENAME2, 2)
    IF @OWNER2 IS NULL SELECT @OWNER2 = 'DBO'
    SELECT @DB2 = PARSENAME(@TABLENAME2, 3) 
    IF @DB2 IS NULL SELECT @DB2 = DB_NAME()

    -- IF OUR TEMP TABLES EXIST, DROP THEM
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TEMPDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '##T1_MAIN') DROP TABLE ##T1_MAIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TEMPDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '##T2_ARCHIVE') DROP TABLE ##T2_ARCHIVE

    -- GATHER SCHEMA INFO FOR LIVE TABLE
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME, 
                COLUMN_NAME, 
                DATA_TYPE, 
                ISNULL(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,0) AS CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
                ISNULL(NUMERIC_PRECISION,0) AS NUMERIC_PRECISION,
                ISNULL(NUMERIC_SCALE,0) AS NUMERIC_SCALE,
                IS_NULLABLE,
                CAST(0 AS BIT) AS ADD_COLUMN,
                CAST(0 AS BIT) AS ALTER_COLUMN
                INTO ##T1_MAIN
                FROM ' + @DB1 + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @TABLE1 + '''
                AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @OWNER1 + ''' '
    --PRINT @SQL
    EXEC(@SQL)

    -- CHECK IF TABLES EXIST, ELSE SKIP ALL WORK
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TEMPDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '##T1_MAIN')
    BEGIN
        PRINT @TABLENAME + ' DOES NOT EXIST, EXITING PROC'
        GOTO SKIPWORK
    END

    -- GATHER SCHEMA INFO FOR ARCHIVE TABLE
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME, 
                COLUMN_NAME, 
                DATA_TYPE, 
                ISNULL(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,0) AS CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
                ISNULL(NUMERIC_PRECISION,0) AS NUMERIC_PRECISION,
                ISNULL(NUMERIC_SCALE,0) AS NUMERIC_SCALE,  
                IS_NULLABLE,         
                CAST(0 AS BIT) AS DROP_COLUMN
                INTO ##T2_ARCHIVE
                FROM ['+@SSERVERNAME+'].' + @DB2 + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @TABLE2 + ''' 
                AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @OWNER2 + ''' '
    --PRINT @SQL
    EXEC(@SQL)

    -- CHECK IF TABLES EXIST, ELSE SKIP ALL WORK
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TEMPDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '##T2_ARCHIVE')
    BEGIN
        PRINT @TABLENAME2 + ' DOES NOT EXIST, EXITING PROC'
        GOTO SKIPWORK
    END

    -- FLAG NEW COLUMNS
    -- COLUMN IN T1 (LIVE) BUT NOT IN T2 (ARCHIVE)
    UPDATE T1 SET ADD_COLUMN = 1
    FROM ##T1_MAIN T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ##T2_ARCHIVE T2
       ON T1.COLUMN_NAME = T2.COLUMN_NAME
    WHERE T2.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL

    -- FLAG REMOVED COLUMNS
    -- COLUMN IN T2 (ARCHIVE) BUT NOT IN T1 (LIVE)
    -- ** NOT DOING ANYTHING WITH THIS **
    UPDATE T2 SET DROP_COLUMN = 1
    FROM ##T2_ARCHIVE T2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ##T1_MAIN T1
       ON T2.COLUMN_NAME = T1.COLUMN_NAME
    WHERE T1.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL

    -- FLAG ALTERED COLUMNS     
    -- ONLY NEED WHERE LIVE DATA LENGTH IS > THAN ARCHIVE DATA LENGTH
    -- WE WOULDN'T WANT TO SHRINK A COLUMN AND TRUNCATE A VALUE           
    UPDATE T1 SET ALTER_COLUMN = 1
    FROM ##T1_MAIN T1
    JOIN ##T2_ARCHIVE T2
       ON T1.COLUMN_NAME = T2.COLUMN_NAME
       AND (T1.DATA_TYPE <> T2.DATA_TYPE
            OR T1.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH > T2.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
            OR T1.NUMERIC_PRECISION > T2.NUMERIC_PRECISION
            OR T1.NUMERIC_SCALE > T2.NUMERIC_SCALE
            OR (T1.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' AND T2.IS_NULLABLE = 'NO'))

    DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(100),
            @DATA_TYPE VARCHAR(100),
            @CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH INT,
            @NUMERIC_PRECISION INT,
            @NUMERIC_SCALE INT,
            @IS_NULLABLE VARCHAR(3)

    -- CREATE A TEMP TABLE TO HOLD OUR COMMANDS FOR EMAIL
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TEMPDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '##COMMANDLIST') DROP TABLE ##COMMANDLIST

    CREATE TABLE ##COMMANDLIST (sText VARCHAR(1000))

    DECLARE ALTER_COLUMN CURSOR LOCAL
    FOR
       SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE, IS_NULLABLE
       FROM ##T1_MAIN
       WHERE ALTER_COLUMN=1

       OPEN ALTER_COLUMN

       FETCH NEXT FROM ALTER_COLUMN INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE, @CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, @NUMERIC_PRECISION, @NUMERIC_SCALE, @IS_NULLABLE

       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
          SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @DB2 + '.' + @OWNER2 + '.' + @TABLE2 + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + CASE 
                                                                                                                        WHEN @DATA_TYPE IN ('NCHAR','NVARCHAR','CHAR','VARCHAR') THEN @DATA_TYPE + ' (' + CAST(@CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(15)) + ')'
                                                                                                                        WHEN @DATA_TYPE IN ('TINYINT','SMALLINT','INT','BIGINT','BIT','UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') THEN @DATA_TYPE
                                                                                                                        WHEN @DATA_TYPE IN ('DECIMAL','MONEY','FLOAT','NUMERIC') THEN @DATA_TYPE + ' (' + CAST(@NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR(15)) + ',' + CAST(@NUMERIC_SCALE AS VARCHAR(15)) + ')'
                                                                                                                     END
                                                                                                                     + ' ' +
                                                                                                                     CASE
                                                                                                                        WHEN @IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'NULL'
                                                                                                                        ELSE 'NULL'
                                                                                                                     END
          PRINT @SQL
          IF @COMMIT_CHANGES = 1 
          BEGIN
             IF(@@SERVERNAME <> @sServerName) SET @SQL = 'EXEC(''' + REPLACE(@SQL,'''','''''') + ''') AT ' + QUOTENAME(@sServerName)   
             EXEC(@SQL)
          END

          IF @SQL IS NOT NULL INSERT INTO ##COMMANDLIST (sText) SELECT @SQL

          FETCH NEXT FROM ALTER_COLUMN INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE, @CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, @NUMERIC_PRECISION, @NUMERIC_SCALE, @IS_NULLABLE
       END
       CLOSE ALTER_COLUMN
    DEALLOCATE ALTER_COLUMN

    DECLARE ADD_COLUMN CURSOR LOCAL
    FOR
       SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE, IS_NULLABLE
       FROM ##T1_MAIN
       WHERE ADD_COLUMN=1

       OPEN ADD_COLUMN

       FETCH NEXT FROM ADD_COLUMN INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE, @CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, @NUMERIC_PRECISION, @NUMERIC_SCALE, @IS_NULLABLE

       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
          SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @DB2 + '.' + @OWNER2 + '.' + @TABLE2 + ' ADD ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + CASE 
                                                                                                               WHEN @DATA_TYPE IN ('NCHAR','NVARCHAR','CHAR','VARCHAR') THEN @DATA_TYPE + ' (' + CAST(@CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(15)) + ')'
                                                                                                               WHEN @DATA_TYPE IN ('TINYINT','SMALLINT','INT','BIGINT','BIT','UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') THEN @DATA_TYPE
                                                                                                               WHEN @DATA_TYPE IN ('DECIMAL','MONEY','FLOAT','NUMERIC') THEN @DATA_TYPE + ' (' + CAST(@NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR(15)) + ',' + CAST(@NUMERIC_SCALE AS VARCHAR(15)) + ')'
                                                                                                            END
                                                                                                            + ' ' +
                                                                                                            CASE
                                                                                                               WHEN @IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'NULL'
                                                                                                               ELSE 'NOT NULL'
                                                                                                            END
          PRINT @SQL
          IF @COMMIT_CHANGES = 1 
          BEGIN
             IF(@@SERVERNAME <> @sServerName) SET @SQL = 'EXEC(''' + REPLACE(@SQL,'''','''''') + ''') AT ' + QUOTENAME(@sServerName)   
             -- uncomment this EXEC to make the commit changes flag work...
             --EXEC(@SQL)
          END

          IF @SQL IS NOT NULL INSERT INTO ##COMMANDLIST (sText) SELECT @SQL

          FETCH NEXT FROM ADD_COLUMN INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE, @CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, @NUMERIC_PRECISION, @NUMERIC_SCALE, @IS_NULLABLE
       END
       CLOSE ADD_COLUMN
    DEALLOCATE ADD_COLUMN

    SKIPWORK:
```

Comment: Hello- Thank you for the code so far. When I run it, I get------- TEST MODE ONLY, CHANGES WILL NOT BE MADE
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 84 Cannot resolve the collation conflict between      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: The collation between your databases are different.  Line 84 is "ON T1.COLUMN_NAME = T2.COLUMN_NAME".  This fits the error, just add "COLLATE DATEBASE_DEFAULT" to the end of that line to make the collation equal.  You may need to add to 2-3 locations to run successfully.

Comment: I added COLLATE DATABASE DEFAULT to line 84. Then the error moved to line 87, as you predicted. However, when I add that statement to line 87, I get "Invalid collation 'DATEBASE_DEFAULT'"

Comment: Sorry, typo:  use DATABASE_DEFAULT not DATEBASE_DEFAULT

Comment: LOL, I didn't even notice that typo or I would have tried it the other way. This looks like it will do what I need. The test output works. I am going to backup my DB before I try the actual modifier step. Thanks!